# Android play video Logcat error [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mp4, codec

I'm getting those errors on the logcat when playing a video

**Logcat** :

```
E/VDO_LOG(132): [Err] ? un-support type of NAL
E/OMXCodec(132): [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer, mFilledBuffers size=17
E/FlvExtractor(132): [ERROR]:Not an FLV file!!!
```

It doesn't crash the program but sometimes I see some bug in the video

**video player code** :

```
    String fileName = "android.resource://" +  getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myVideo;
    vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
    vv.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    vv.start();
```

**the video file informations** :

```
  length : 8 seconds
  width : 720 px
  height : 1280 px
  total data rate : 5403 kbits / s
  fps : 25 images / s
  type : MP4
  codec : H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) (avc1)
```

What could be the problem, and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) is the problem. most android devices won't play it. nothing wrong with your code. 
Check this link of what does work. You need an MPEG-4 Baseline stream.
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations